# Automatically get a different status for an authorized vs. captured payment?

Tags: paypal, authorization, capture, status

Is there a way or an extension out there that allows a Magento order to get a different status automatically once a payment has been captured?

The reason why we're looking for this is because we connect to ShipStation (www.shipstation.com) for shipping and eCC Webgility (www.webgility.com) to post orders to our accounting software.  We need a more automated way for those orders that get pulled in for us to know whether the order has had funds captured or not.  The only way for us to do this now is manually change the order status since Magento's default method keeps the order in "processing" regardless of it being invoiced or not.

Comment: Are you using Payments Pro or another PayPal solution?

Comment: I am using Payments Pro

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to do all of that with an [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) solution.

For any transaction that ever hits your PayPal account, whether it's a payment, a refund, a cleared or failed pending payment, disputes, etc. their server will POST the transaction data to a listener script on your server.

Within this script you can use that data to update your database, generate custom email notifications, hit 3rd party web service API's, etc. all automatically, in real-time.

Comment: Is this a "stock" functionality for the PayPal integration in Magento?  If so, I did not see any setting for changing a status depending on whether or not the funds were authorized or captured.

Comment: I think Magento uses IPN in a limited fashion just to update itself when using Payments Standard.  I'm not sure about when using Payments Pro or Express checkout, though.  For a fully customized solution, though, you'll probably just want to write your own solution anyway, or you could extend the IPN functionality in Magento.